# I made a jquery script and I need help on how to make it auto switch between the 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this script auto change between the four after 30 seconds, I am not to good at jquery but I wanted to give it a try. This is all on a .php page I am using  to bring up the javascript from my other folders.

```
<div id="subnavi">
<div id="subnavi-user">
<div style="margin-top:7px"><b>Fact:</b> <script language="JavaScript">

var r_text = new Array ();      
r_text[0] = "{hotelName} was founded in 2011 by Kyle";
r_text[1] = "{hotelName} strives to remain as professional as possible.";       
r_text[2] = "{hotelName} will only keep on growing if you vote daily!";                             
r_text[3] = "Purchasing VIP in the forums helps with the monthly server costs.";
r_text[4] = "{hotelName} Is a new and developing RP!";

window.setInterval(function(){

var i = Math.floor(4 * Math.random())


document.write(r_text[i]);

var random = r_text[1];

}, 5000);





</script>
</div>

</div>

<div id="subnavi-search">
<div id="subnavi-search-upper">
<ul id="subnavi-search-links">
<li><a href="{url}/logout" style="color:#000">Sign Out</a></li>
```

Comment: what exactly is your goal here? are you trying to switch between them on a timer? or on the click of the button?

Comment: I want it on a timer, my bad at not being clear about that.

Comment: I think you are looking for javascript's setInterval.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a tutorial on setInterval? I am pretty new to Jquery and I would love to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here it is:
This script will run every time you reload the page. IF you need it to work in a different way just update your question and i will update my script.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "Hello";
r_text[1] = "Test";
r_text[2] = "We are the lions";
r_text[3] = "Fight";
r_text[4] = "Switch!";

window.setInterval(function(){
    var i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random())
    var random = r_text[i];

    $('#r_text').html(random);
}, 5000); // you can change the interval here
```

The HTML part

```
<div id="r_text"></div>
```

Check this out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crematorio/q8f7g/)

**Update** 
Change your `Math.floor` to count to 5 because your array has 5 elements in it not 4

**Update 2** Your file should look like something like this

```
<!Document html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "Hello";
r_text[1] = "Test";
r_text[2] = "We are the lions";
r_text[3] = "Fight";
r_text[4] = "Switch!";

window.setInterval(function(){
    var i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random())
    var random = r_text[i];

    $('#r_text').html(random);
}, 5000); // you can change the interval here
</script>   
</head>
<body>
  //Add your html/php code here and pick a place where to show the response of your function. Something like <div id="r_text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like the clean cut of it but I am looking for away to make the r_text auto change after 30 seconds or so.

Comment: For some reason the text won't show up on my page no more I will make a better post of my whole php page.

Comment: @Kyleeck it works on jsfiddle. Did you add the html part on your page? Just update your post with the html/php part where you are trying to show the results and also show us how you link your js file to your .php file

Comment: The jquery code is on the .php page I did not make it in a jquery thing. I am pretty new to jquery but trying to learn it.

Comment: let me fix your code in jsfiddle and post it back. @Kyleeck

Comment: Okay thanks I can show you the whole .php page I am using if you need to see it.

Comment: you can send it to me if you want. Find me email in my profile page

Comment: I sent you a message on your website page.